# WP8 Check if app has update

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to implement a notification for user to update the app.

So how can I check if my application has an update (or newer version) on the store?

Edit: what I am looking for is a build-in api

Comment: @MatthewHaugen ok i see that, thanks. i am taking back part of my comment

Comment: may be this can help http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh202945%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: @Devjosh It's all good. I deleted my comment as well.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely true that you could set up a server-side feature to push notifications (or even just check when the app starts for something like this) of whether there was an update available. That'd be pretty easy to set up. But I definitely think there *should* be some way of doing this through a Windows Phone API. It's a pretty simple task, that a lot of apps probably have to do in one way or another. But I couldn't find any built in way in my searches.

Comment: Although, just for the record, Windows Phone 8.1 is being rolled out now, and it does automatically update apps in the background, data and settings permitting. So this is becoming less of an issue than before. Not to mention, with the Action Center, users are already being informed of updates by the OS in a way that they'll actually see. So it's an interesting question, but I'm not sure it will be relevant to most devices in, say, three months.

Comment: @matthew , i usually develop in asp.net but when searched found the relevant link to the question so posted but the things you shared are intresting to know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58047/discussion-between-devjosh-and-matthew-haugen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a XAML behavior that checks for updates in the [WpWinNl toolkit](http://wpwinnl.codeplex.com/). Here is a blogpost by Joost Van Schaik on how to implement it:

http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2013/09/zero-lines-of-code-solution-for-in-app.html

Comment: Very interesting! Why can't I see this on Google

Comment: Let me know if you have any trouble implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution targeted to Windows Phone 8 using Cimbalino Windows Phone Toolkit:
http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Application_update_prompt_using_Cimbalino_Windows_Phone_Toolkit

Edit: simpler solution without any toolkits http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Checking_for_updates_from_inside_a_Windows_Phone_app

Comment: thanks for provided more than 1 solutions. The second one is simple but works very well.

Comment: Yep, I'm using the second one as well. Took just a few minutes to implement :)

Comment: @JukkaRautanen, can you please update these links? can't find them as Nokia Developer site is moved